Pullback of vector field under inclusion map
Suppose we have a manifold $X$ embedded in ambient space (this is $\mathbb{P}^n$),
$$ \iota: X \hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^n. $$
Given a vector field on $\mathbb{P}^n$, is there any way, canonical or otherwise, to pullback the vector field to $X$? i.e. find
$$ \iota^* v, \, v \in \Gamma(T_{\mathbb{P}^n}). $$
For $k$-forms in the ambient space the pullback is quite straightforward, but the pullback of a vector field along a map $f$ seems to require that $f$ be a diffeomorphism ...

How do you pullback a vector field on $\mathbb{R}^3$ to the unit sphere $S^2$? You could do a pointwise orthogonal projection of the vector field, but I wouldn't call that a pullback.

Yes, the only way I could think of was finding a basis for the normal space and orthogonally projecting $v_p \in T\mathbb{P}^n_p$ using the ambient space metric.

Orthogonal projection doesn't sound too promising if you're working in the holomorphic category. Can you give more context for your question?

@Ted Shifrin The problem is related to Kodaira-Spencer theory: given a holomorphic family of Calabi-Yau manifolds $ \pi: \mathcal{X} \rightarrow B$ where the fibres $X_b = \pi^{-1}(b)$ have $c_1(X_b) = 0$, given a tangent vector $\partial / \partial t^i$ on the base $B$, I want to compute a (not necessarily horizontal) lift to $\mathcal{X}$ and restrict this to the fibres. The problem is the vector field coming from the lifting lives in $\mathbb{P}^n$ and I want to restrict this to the fibres somehow in a natural way.

This sounds like you might want to apply the Ehresmann Theorem.

@TedShifrin could you elaborate further? I can't see how it immediately applies.

In that setting, you get a bundle structure on $\mathcal X$ and you can put an Ehresmann connection on $T\mathcal X$.
